# PySpark dataframe to python dataframe doesn't carry nested list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have this pyspark dataframe as:

```
 |-- countryCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- words: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- confidence: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- locale: string (nullable = true)
```

I am trying to convert it to Python Dataframe, but the list of dictionaries as "words" won't keep their format of list of dictionaries. They become list of tuples.
How could I avoid it?

in pyspark:

[Row(countryCode='TR', words=[Row(confidence='0.50127727', locale='en')]]

converting to python dataframe:

```
scraped_data.select("countryCode", "words").toPandas()
```

python dataframe:

countryCode   words

TR            [(0.50127727, en)]

what I want is the list of dictionaries in my python dataframe for "words" as **[{'confidence':'0.50127727', 'locale':'en'}]**

Answer (score 0):

Convert struct to Map Type using pyspark's `create_map()` before you send to pandas. `create_map()` is a PySpark SQL function that converts `StructType` to `MapType` column.

Data

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row
df= spark.createDataFrame([Row(countryCode='TR', Words =[Row(confidence='0.50127727', locale='en')])])
df.show()
```

Solution

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,lit,create_map
df = df.withColumn("WordsMap",create_map(
        lit("confidence"),col("Words.confidence"),
        lit("locale"),col("Words.locale")
        )).drop("Words")
pdf =df.select("countryCode", "WordsMap").toPandas()
```

Outcome

```
print(pdf)



 countryCode                         WordsMap
0          TR     {'confidence': ['0.50127727'], 'locale': ['en']}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! But this solution doesn't work if each row in my dataframe has different size of array in words: array.
    US {'locale': ['en', 'en'], 'confidence': ['0.605', '0.78']}

what I want to have is list of objects not objects of list.

Comment: Good, please give a sample table in put and desired output

Comment: What is your exact expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when we convert the pyspark dataframe to python dataframe,  the format of dictionaries' list will be showed no preserved, but the format is preserved in the new dataframe too and you can access the key-value stores:

```
for idx, row in scraped_data_df.iterrows():
    for kw in row['words']:
        if kw['confidence'] not in test.keys():
```

it basically have all the dictionary fields in it even if it dataframe.head() only shows tuples: [(0.50127727, en)]